# Dart decode escaped JSON

Tags: json, dart

I'm trying to deserialize a simple `JSON` object from an `API`.
The API returns the `JSON` in escaped quotes since the data represents a user's quote.

```
test("escaped quoted json test", () {
  var s = '''{"quote": "\"a quote from a user\""}''';

  var b = json.decode(s);
  expect(b["quote"], "\"a quote from a user\"");
});
```

However this throws:

> FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 13)
>   `{"quote": ""a quote from a user""}`

Btw the JSON is valid:

```
{"quote": "\"a quote from a user\""}
```

[image]

How do I tell `Dart` to handle this correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's just invalid JSON. The server/sender has to escape quotes inside strings.

Comment: It is escaped. So it is valid according to https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Then there won't be a problem.

Comment: So why is it then?

Comment: There is literally a failing test,  with an expected output.... 
What more info do you want?

Comment: You are right. I deleted my comment. It's just that source is no equivalent to JSON received from outside the app. See my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The inner quote needs to be escaped with a literal backslash not an escaped backslash

```
var s = '''{"quote": "\\"a quote from a user\\""}''';
```

or

```
var s = r'''{"quote": "\"a quote from a user\""}''';
```

There is a difference between JSON written in Dart source code and JSON received over network.
If you put it in source like in your question, the string is interpreted.   You can either adapt the string (double all `\`) or prefix it with `r` for raw string.

Comment: Thanks. This explains a lot.  
Be sure not to judge a question to quickly next time.